# Solution or algorithm for linear diophantine equations with unit coefficients

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I am interested in nonnegative integer solutions $\{x_{mq}\}$ to a particular type of linear system. The system can be broken into a "horizontal" and "vertical" subsystem; that is, the horizontal subsystem is as follows

$$x_{11} + x_{12} + \ldots + x_{1Q} = h_1 $$
$$x_{21} + x_{22} + \ldots + x_{2Q} = h_2 $$
$$\vdots$$
$$x_{M1} + x_{M2} + \ldots + x_{MQ} = h_M $$

whereas the vertical system is
$$x_{11} + x_{21} + \ldots + x_{M1} = v_1 $$
$$x_{12} + x_{22} + \ldots + x_{M2} = v_2 $$
$$\vdots$$
$$x_{1Q} + x_{2Q} + \ldots + x_{MQ} = v_Q $$

for constants $h_1, \ldots, h_M$ and $v_1, \ldots , v_Q$.

So the vertical system are simply summing restrictions formed from the "columns" of the horizontal system. In matrix form, the systems can be written as
$$
X 1_Q = h
$$
$$
X' 1_M = v
$$
where $1_K$ denotes the vector of ones in $\mathbb{R}^K$.

I doubt that this system has a closed form for the family of solutions (but would be very glad to be proved wrong!). Does a straightforward algorithm exist instead? The plan that I'm currently implementing is as follows:

1. Enumerate all solutions $x_{m1}, x_{m2}, \ldots , x_{mQ}$ to the horizontal system for each $m$.
2. Iterate through all combinations of the above solutions, eliminating combinations that violate the vertical solution.

As one might guess, this is not a terribly efficient algorithm. I can save much time by placing restrictions on the horizontal solutions I find in (1) by first eliminating any that have $x_{mq} > v_q$. Even so, with just $M = Q = 6$, I'd be iterating over a list with something on the order of tens of billions of elements.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to me as if a solution for a given vector $H$ (columnvector of $h$'s) and $V$ (rowvector of $v$'s) would always be constructable as a matrix with a diagonal and one lower subdiagonal, (and perhaps one upper subdiagonal - but possibly this is not needed). To analyze this set $x_{1,1}=1$ then $x_{1,2}=h_1-1$ and the rest of the row $1$ to zero. Then $x_{2,1}=v_1-1$, $x_{2,2}=??$ and the rest of the row to zero. And so on. Perhaps beginning with $x_{1,1}=h_1$ , $x_{1,2..n}=0$ gives an even smarter solution.

Comment: What do you mean by $X'1_M = v$? Do you mean $1_M X = v$ instead?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva $X'$ denotes the transpose, so $1_M X = v$ is equivalent if $v$ is a row vector.

Comment: @Ken: Ok good to know, I was asking because the usual notation for the transpose is $X^T$ or $X^{\top}$ (in LaTeX/MathJax, you need to write \top).

Answer (score 1):

I'm exploring this, so for the beginning I assume, that the matrix $XX$ is a square-matrix, with *#rows=#cols=n*.

First we note, that $\sum_{k=1}^n h_k = \sum_{k=1}^n v_k $, so $v_n $ is not free to be set arbitrarily but is determined by the other given coefficients.

Keeping this in mind I begin with the matrix $XX=\{x_{r,c} \}_{r,c=1..n}=0$, and initially filling in $x_{1,1}=h_1$.
The sum of the first row gives now correctly $h_1$.

Now the first column needs a compensation to be able to sum up to $v_1$: in the second row $x_{2,1}$ I set $x_{2,1}=v_1-x_{1,1}$ .
From this follows the setting of $x_{2,2}=h_2-x_{2,1}$, then $x_{3,2}=v_2-x_{2,2}$     and so on with that simple recursive algorithm, down to the bottom right entry.

With an example of $n=4$ I get the following solution:
$$ \small\begin{array} {rrrr|r}
h_1&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&h_1\\
v_1-h_1&h_1+h_2-v_1&\cdot&\cdot&h_2\\
\cdot&(v_1+v_2)-(h_1+h_2)&(h_1+h_2+h_3)-(v_1+v_2)&\cdot&h_3\\
\cdot&\cdot&(v_1+v_2+v_3)-(h_1+h_2+h_3)&(h_1+h_2+h_3+h_4)-(v_1+v_2+v_3)&h_4\\\hline
v_1&v_2&v_3&v_4&\cdot\\
\end{array}$$
Note that I've appended the rowsums at the right and the column-sums at the bottom.
Note also, that the last entry $x_{4,4}$ requires (or simply: expresses) the equality which I've mentioned at the beginning of this post.